# Object leaked... how can i solve it?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

When i do "Build and analyze" xCode gives me the following warning:

**Potential leak of an object allocated on line 70**

1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)
2. Looping back to the head of the loop
3. Object allocated on line 70 is no longer referenced after this point and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

This is the code (line 70 is the one that begins with "NSString *newString"):

```
for(int j = 1; j < [smokeArray count]; j++) {

    NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Data: "]; 
    int f = [[[smokeArray objectAtIndex:j] num] intValue];

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        int d = [[[[smokeArray objectAtIndex:j] dat] objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if (i>0) {  newString = [newString stringByAppendingFormat:@"-%d",d];   }
        else {  newString = [newString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",d];  }

    }

    NSLog(@"%d, %@", f, newString);
}
```

Comment: It's not related to your question, but unless you took some code out it looks like that inner for loop is kind of useless - you're setting the newString value but not doing anything with it. Does your NSLog always print "X, Data: 6"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to `autorelease`:

```
NSString *newString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Data: "] autorelease];
```

Or in the specific case as posted above simply:

```
NSString *newString = @"Data: ";
```

Answer (score 2):

`stringByAppendingFormat` returns a new `autoreleased` string. The original `newString` does not get released.
You will be better off using `NSMutableString` and `appendFormat`.

```
for(int j = 1; j < [smokeArray count]; j++) {

    NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Data: "]; 
    int f = [[[smokeArray objectAtIndex:j] num] intValue];

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        int d = [[[[smokeArray objectAtIndex:j] dat] objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if ( d > 0) {  [newString appendFormat:@"-%d",d];   } // fixed a potential logic error ( i > 0 )
        else { [newString appendFormat:@"%d",d];  }

    }

    NSLog(@"%d, %@", f, newString);
    // Do something useful like set a label or property with the string
    [newString release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive answer! But please, edit it because it is not correct: the appendFormat method does not return a new string, it only modify the receiver. So:

[newString appendFormat:@"%d",d];

instead of

newString = [newString appendFormat:@"%d",d];

Comment: Good catch. Removed the unnecessary re-assignment to newString. Using NSMutableString will reduce your overall memory footprint compared to creating new NSString instances with `stringWithFormat`.